# select on non-blocking sockets

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I apologize if this question is duplication of some other similar question.

I am setting small servers-clients on few systems which are quite low on load (Not more than 10-15 connections at a time which will also do very low data transfer). I was wondering if I should use blocking or non-blocking sockets?

On a server side I am using select and when it returns I go and read fds. Now if I use non-blocking sockets with select then what is the advantage in "recv" which follows select. Can there be a situation where select tells you there is something available to read but actually there is nothing to read?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if I should use blocking or non-blocking sockets?

For such low load, I would use blocking sockets and give each socket its own dedicated thread to run in.  That being said, `select()` works for both blocking and non-blocking sockets, if you are not comfortable with multithreaded programming.

> Can there be a situation where select tells you there is something available to read but actually there is nothing to read?

Yes.  On a graceful disconnect, `select()` reports a socket is readable, and then `recv()` on that socket returns 0.

Comment: I meant can it happen that for blocking sockets, select returns for a fd and when I call read it gets blocked as there is nothing to read.

Comment: Yes, it can, but only if multiple threads are reading from the same socket at the same time. If one thread calls `recv()`, the other thread can block on `recv()`. To avoid conflicts, never have multiple threads reading from the same socket.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Remy.

But, I suggest you don't use threads.  At least not to begin with.  The reason I suggest this is because it sounds like you're kinda new to this type of thing and threads may just add more headaches for you than you need in order to get basic comms up and running.

Comment: So you agree but you don't agree? Which is it?

Comment: I agree. Given that he seems new to this, I think threads will just add complications that he could evade.  He can use select with blocking sockets just as well (as mentioned by Remy).  Also, fork() works very well in situations like this (as long as you're not on windows). And is usually easier to grasp.